# Set polyline with relative points using SVG document

Tags: html, svg, polyline

Using `flex` I have two adjacent `div`(s), where the first container will dynamically set the height based on the content, and the latter will follow be 100% of its height.

In the latter `div`, an SVG document at full height draws a `polyline`. However, despite the SVG document resizing its height, the polyline point are fixed in absolute values, thus not responsive.

*At normal width:*
[image: At normal width]

*Once the width is shrunk:*
[image: on a smaller width]

*intended result should scale:*
[image: the svg scales appropriately]

Would it somehow be possible to set points relative to SVG document size, or perhaps set some point from 0,0 axis and the rest from the bottom?

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/khaled_nabil/jov9cstg/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is change your preserveAspectRatio to none, but that will stretch the stroke as well.

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/majnhguz/

Update:
You can address that by by using this on your path:

```
vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rv9kup7z/